# Backbone.js routing conditional default route

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a router with a number of different options, for one instance I need to load one of the routes, which works well, however the default route which is always called loads in some additional templates.
 Just wondered if there is a way to say if this route in this case CMS, then don't load elements from the default route. 
Code from my router :

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/common/header',
  'views/common/menu',
  'views/rightPanel',
  'views/landing',
  'views/personalBanking',
  'views/currentAccounts',
  'views/signIn',
  'views/cms/cmsView',
], function($, _, Backbone, headerView, menuView, rightPanelView, landingView, personalBankingView, accountsView, signInView, CMS){

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        currentView: null,

        initialize: function() {
            this.showView(headerView);
            this.showView(menuView);
            //TODO set for TV-width
            if($(window).width() > 180) {
                this.showView(rightPanelView);
            }
        },

        routes: {
            '': 'defaultAction',
            'personal': 'showPersonalBankingView',
            'accounts': 'showCurrentAccountsView',
            'signIn': 'showSignInView',
            'CMS': 'CMSView',
        },



        defaultAction: function(actions){
            this.showView(landingView);
        },

        showPersonalBankingView: function(actions){
            this.showView(personalBankingView);
        },

        showCurrentAccountsView: function(actions){
            this.showView(accountsView);
        },

        showSignInView: function(actions){
            this.showView(signInView);
        },

        CMSView: function(actions){
            this.showView(CMS);
            console.log("cms view going on");
        },

        showView: function(view) {
            view.render();
            if(view.postRender) {
                view.postRender();
            }   
        }
    });

    var initialize = function(){
        new AppRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

If I have not explained in enough detail please ask me for more information, looking forward to some help I am very new to backbone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your default action to the bottom of the routes dictionary so that it will not be matched first but rather as a last resort when all other routes fail.

```
routes: {
    'personal': 'showPersonalBankingView',
    'accounts': 'showCurrentAccountsView',
    'signIn': 'showSignInView',
    'CMS': 'CMSView',
    '': 'defaultAction'
},
```